# Cohomology of formal completion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $(R,m)$ be a complete regular local ring.  Let $U=\operatorname{Spec}R-\{m\}$ be the complementary open set of a closed point in $\operatorname{Spec}R$, and let $I$ be the ideal of $R$. Then it is stated that $\operatorname{H}^0(\hat{U},\mathcal{O}_\hat{U})=\varprojlim_{x\in U\cap V(I)}\mathcal{O}_{\hat{U},x}$, where $\hat{U}$ is the completion of $U$ along $V(I)\cap U$.

Why $\operatorname{H}^0(\hat{U},\mathcal{O}_\hat{U})$ can be written as the inverse limit as above? What is the arrow in this inverse system? I know $\mathcal{O}_{\hat{U}}$ can be expressed as $\varprojlim \mathcal{O}_U/\mathcal{I}^n$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is the sheaf of ideals.

Comment: It is stated where?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez [here](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1973__42__47_0.pdf) on page 72, the second line.

Comment: I think you can use $H^0(\hat{U},\mathcal{O}_{\hat{U}})=\bigcap_{x \in V(I)}\mathcal{O}_{\hat{U},x}$ where the intersection takes place in $Frac(R)$?

Comment: @Sisi Did you mean $\bigcap _{x\in U\cap V(I)}\mathcal O_{\hat{U},x}$?